# Ubuntu 11.04 does not detect my tata photon +

Tags: command-line, internet, devices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure TATA Photon+ EC1261 HUAWEI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6001/how-to-configure-tata-photon-ec1261-huawei)

I am trying to connect to the Internet via my photon+ from the past day and have tried various suggestions on the Internet and have tried to zero in to the main cause of the problem which is that my device is not detected.

I have tried the following ways:

1) After connecting the device, I tried to create a mobile broadband connection via System > Preferences > Network Connections and selected tata photon plus. But there was no connection.

2) I did `sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch-data` 
and `sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch`

But the prompt said that they are at their newest version.

3) I tried to edit the file `sudo gedit /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1446`, but this file did not exist.

4) my `lsusb` output is

`nikhil@nikhil:~$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 22f4:0021

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b159 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Any Ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

Even I use a tata photon plus+ , but it worked seamlessly for me. Though I connect using the gnome-ppp dialer.
To use the gnome-ppp dialer:

Install it by executing `sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp`

Once it is installed execute it by searching for "gnome ppp" in the dash or executing 
`sudo gnome-ppp` in the terminal\using alt+f2.

Once opened gnome-ppp, click on "Setup"

The setup window shall open, now click on "Detect"

Fortunately, if you haven't messed up anything in your modeswitch file, it shall detect your modem.

After it is detected, click on "close"

Type your username and password  (By default the username is "internet" and the password is "internet" ) and click on "connect".

It shall connect to the Internet, showing a window which shows the time since you have connected.

PS: **You must disconnect from all networks before using your Tata Photon +**

Comment: Hi Vibhav, 
Thanks for your reply.
I did the following as suggested by you
1) Installed gnome-ppp client
2) Clicked on detect but it said that `No modem was found on your system.` when I had inserted my tata-photon. 
Is there anything else I can do ?