# Unable to browse internet through Tata Photon Plus after connection is established

Tags: internet

I am unable to browse internet through tata Photon plus after connection is established OK. Ubuntu version is 10.04 LTS

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6001/how-to-configure-tata-photon-ec1261-huawei

follow the above guide .

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with 10.04 but I updated to 12.04. You can try the following:

1. Connect your Photon+ USB modem to the device.
2. Click on the Network Manager applet (the icon to the left of the volume indicator) on the top panel.
3. Click '**Enable Mobile Broadband**' option in the drop down menu.
4. Again, click on the Network Manager applet, select '**Edit Connections...**'.
5. In the '**Network Connections**' dialog box, select the '**Mobile Broadband**' tab and click the '**Add**' button.
6. Select country as **India** then select **Tata Photon+**.
7. Put "**internet**" as username and password. Make sure to tick '**Available to all users**'. Let the number be #777 as it is.
8. Save and Close.
9. Disconnect and reinsert the Photon USB modem.
10. After the blue LED on the USB modem starts blinking, click on network icon and select the tata photon + network. The network will be established and you will be able to browse the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have used the device in some other computer and ejected photon directly,,, plug photon again into the device and eject it properly and try to use it in the new device you want.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit Connections and edit The Wireless Broadband parameters with
username=internet
password=internet