# How to Connect internet using Huawei EC1261 (TATA photon+) on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, networking, internet, usb-modem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure TATA Photon+ EC1261 HUAWEI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6001/how-to-configure-tata-photon-ec1261-huawei)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit) on Dell inspiron 7520 laptop having Intel i7 3rd generation processor. I am trying to connect mobile broadband device and am unable to establish a connection.

**1.** When I try to add mobile broadband connection from 'network connections->mobile broadband' I can not see modem (huawei) in a drop-down in 'New connection' window even if it is connected to laptop.

**2.** When I ran command *lsusb*, output was:

```
$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:648d Microdia

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp.
```

Here, we can see that **12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co** is identified. So I think that ubuntu is not able to recognize it as a modem.

**3.** When I checked usb_moedswitch.rules file, I found entry for this device.

I ran command

```
$ cat /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

and in that file I found entry:

```
#Huawei, newer modems

ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1446", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Ubuntu is not able to recognize this device as a modem, even if this entry is present in this file.

**4.** Just for a trial, I ran command:

```
$ usb_modeswitch -H -v 12d1 -p 1446
```

and got output as-:

```
Looking for default devices ...
found matching product ID
adding device
Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
Accessing device 000 on bus 003 ...
Getting the current device configuration ...
Error getting the current configuration (error -1). Assuming configuration 1.
Using first interface: 0x00
Using endpoints 0x08 (out) and 0x87 (in)
Inquiring device details; driver will be detached ...
Looking for active driver ...
 No driver found. Either detached before or never attached
 Could not claim interface (error -1). Skipping device inquiry
Error: could not get description string "manufacturer"
Error: could not get description string "product"
Error: could not get description string "serial number"

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: 
     Product: 
  Serial No.: 
-------------------------
Sending Huawei control message ...
Error: sending Huawei control message failed (error -1). Aborting.
```

**Question**
I am not sure what is the exact problem and how to solve it. Is it some kind of driver's problem? I am not expert in Ubuntu. Could anyone help me out?

Thanks
-- Kanad

Comment: check out this link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/6001/how-to-configure-tata-photon-ec1261-huawei

Comment: This is not duplicate of How to configure [TATA Photon+ EC1261 HUAWEI] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/6001/how-to-configure-tata-photon-ec1261-huawei). I have already tried this. That link deals with having latest usb_modeswitch and usb_modeswitch_data. I already have these packages to the latest versions. Also that link deals with Ubuntu 10.04 and we here talking here about 12.10.

Comment: As I said above this was not duplicate. Problem was that Ubuntu 12.10 have latest versions of usb_modeswitch and usb_modeswith_data packages already installed. These packages dont work. You need to downgrade these packages to the versions mentioned in (http://askubuntu.com/questions/6001/how-to-configure-tata-photon-ec1261-huawei). For more details see my post: http://coolkanad.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-connect-internet-using-huawei.html