# No "ENABLE BROADBAND" option in network settings of ubuntu 12.10

Tags: network-manager, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, huawei

i used to use 12.04 LTS and had the same problem..upgraded to 12.10 as i have read somewhere that 12.10 has a fix for it...but i still face the same problem..
*i have wvdial...usb-mode switch packages
*my modem also shows up in lsusb command
*i have added my modem under the mobile broadband tab of network settings
*enabled networking in recovery mode

NOTE:-when i boot up in the recovery mode..the option is available in the network settings to "ENABLE BROADBAND" and also my modem shows up and i am able to connect it...but i am unable to do so in the normal boot.

p.s:- i use tata photon +

Comment: Did you check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6001/how-to-configure-tata-photon-ec1261-huawei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/yourtataphoton.rules` to create the file we need. Now paste the content below into the file and save it.

```
SUBSYSTEM="usb"
SYSFS{idProduct}="1446"
SYSFS{idVendor}="12d1"
RUN+="/lib/udev/modem-modeswitch --vendor 0x12d1 --product 0x1446 --type option-zerocd"
```

Now just plug in your dongle and configure your connection using NetworkManager.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/8928/44518)

Comment: thank you for the reply...but i tried it and it aint working...did exactly the same..rebooted and even gave the device some time..but not worth the wait..

Comment: and my /etc/usb-mode/ directory is empty...is that a problem or related to the issue ??

Answer (score 1):

I've got a Sony P11Z netbook with a built-in USB 3G Modem and i'm using debian, maybe my problem is the same as yours.

```
# lsusb -s 001:007
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0af0:7601 Option Globetrotter MO40x 3G Modem (GTM 382)
```

When booting a 3.10 kernel the mobile broadband option usually is missing (but not always). When i boot a 3.2 kernel it shows up again (most often).

I checked /var/log/syslog while restarting network-manager and found these 3 lines:

```
Dec  4 08:31:18 plok NetworkManager[4934]: <info> rfkill0: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:17/SNY5001:00/rfkill/rfkill0) (platform driver Sony Notebook Control Driver)
Dec  4 08:31:18 plok NetworkManager[4934]: <info> rfkill2: found WWAN radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:17/SNY5001:00/rfkill/rfkill2) (platform driver Sony Notebook Control Driver)
Dec  4 08:31:18 plok NetworkManager[4934]: <info> rfkill3: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill3) (driver ath9k)
```

Now i found out that, in my case, issuing the following command would bring up the device, regardless of the currently running kernel.
It takes a few seconds to initialize (follow the process with tail -f /var/log/syslog), then the "mobile broadband" option would show up in gnome-network-manager.

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:17/SNY5001:00/rfkill/rfkill2/state
```